# Can I have multiple display templates for an object in ASP.NEt MVC 3?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to have multiple display templates for the same object in asp.net mvc?

In my situation I have a `Comment` object. I would like to use DisplayFor to automatically loop throught an IEnumerable in my view and display the proper template for each item.  This works great. Now say I have another view where I also need to display a list of comments in the same manner...But I wants these comments to be editable by the user.

So basically, Can I have 2 display templates, one for read-only display and one for editable display(or other similar scenarios)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [EditorTemplate](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx)

You could also specify the templateName in the [DisplayFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor.aspx) methods.